# 100% bounce rate on page that doesn't bounce

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bounce-rate

I have a page `/blah/` that has a very high bounce rate – often it's up to 100%.

Thing is, people are 100% without question clicking links on this page such as `/blah/shirley.htm` i.e users aren't bouncing.

I know this because pages such as `/blah/shirley.htm` are only accessible by clicking a link on `/blah/`.

The pages are all noindex to Google and the pages only went live today so there is no other way to access them.

So how can a page have 100% bounce when people are clicking links on that page?

I'm using Google Analytics.

Comment: If you just launched the pages today, I suspect that Google hasn't computed the bounce rates yet.   Google Analytics stats usually get updated the next day.

Comment: Hi sorry should have been clearer.. The page /blah/ has been live some time. The pages like /blah/Shirley.htm only went live yesterday.

But then should I not be worrying about the 100% reported figure for /blah/ until the following day because of the lag?

Still don't understand why other pages like /Shirley.htm are being reached and have a bounce of 0

K

Answer (score 1):

> The pages are all noindex to Google and the pages only went live today
>   so there is no other way to access them.

Firstly, just because they went live today doesn't mean they won't be indexed today, I have had pages indexed the same day many times.

Secondly,

They are probably indexed on a whole load of other search engines. Try blocking in your robots.txt file to all other search engines.